# Does any scripture mention about Chanakya other than the Srimad Bhagavatham?

Tags: scripture, history, reference-request

Srimad Baghavatham has an indirect mention to [Chanakya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanakya):

> A certain brāhmaṇa [Cāṇakya] will betray the trust of King Nanda and
> his eight sons and will destroy their dynasty. In their absence the
> Mauryas will rule the world as the Age of Kali continues.
>
> [[12.1.11]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/1/11/)

Does any other scripture have similar mentions, either directly or indirectly, about Chanakya?